# How can I get more Telegram stickers?

Tags: telegram

I've recently noticed loads of cool Telegram stickers making their way around. How are people getting these cool things? How can I add more stickers? How can I be cooler than them?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's quite straightforward actually](https://telegram.org/blog):

## Sending a Sticker

Pick an emoji, then in the message field, tap on it again

[image: SendingEmoji]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge</sub>

Alternatively, you can access the stickers menu in the emoji keyboard

[image: emoji keyboard]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge</sub>

## Getting More Stickers

> Sending a link isn‘t the only way to share a sticker set. When you receive a sticker from a set you do not currently have installed, simply tap on it and choose ’Add to Stickers‘ to preview and add the whole set.

If someone sends you a cool sticker you like, simply tap and hold on the sticker and select *Add To Stickers* in the dialog box that appears.

[image: Stick add]

<sub>Screenshot - Click to enlarge</sub>

You can then manage your stickers in the Stickers menu in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

To add any stickers to your collection, tap on a sticker and click on 'Add to Stickers'.

You can look at different places to see new stickers. Try chatting with @ratestickerbot that will ask you for ratings of new stickers.